# Build OpencvBlobsLib em Ambiente Windows

Tags: opencv

Como executar a compilação da bilioteca OpenCVBlobsLib em Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (funciona em versões anteriores)

Comment: Você deu menos de 1 minuto para as pessoas responderem, hahaha. I know what you are trying to do here. ;)

Comment: eu respondi a minha propria pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passo a passo (eu coloquei este tutorial em issues do github mas foi fechado)

1. Eu realizei o download do cvBlobslib (https://github.com/OpenCVBlobsLib/opencvblobslib)
2. Criar um projeto vazio no Visual Studio 2013
3. Colocar os 6 arquivos .h e 5 arquivos .cpp no projeto
4. Realizar o binding de todas as dependências OpenCV (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v-VgWxkVp2w)
5. Fazer o download deste arquivo: 1.17MB pthreads-w32-2-9-1-release.zip
   e descompacte na pasta: `C:\pthreads.hWin32` (eu criei esta pasta)
6. Esta pasta tem 3 subpastas: `Pre-built.2`, `pthreads.2`, `QueueUserAPCEx`.
7. `Pre-built.2` tinha 3 subpastas: `Lib` (2 subpastas: x64 com libpthreadGC2.a (Extensão .a) e pthreadVC2.lib, x86 eu não uso) e `dll`, incluem com 3 .h.
8. Adicione a pasta `include` no `Additional include directories(MVS)`.
9. Adicione a pasta `lib` em `Additional include directories`.
10. Adicione `pthreadVC2.lib` dentro da pasta lib
11. Mudar o "Tipo de Configuração" em Configuration Properties -->> General para Static Library .lib
12. Adicionar esta linha acima de todos os arquivos .cpp:
    `pragma warning (disable: 4996) // Esta função ou variável pode ser inseguro`
13. No menu principal, selecione `Release / x64` e eu cliquei em `BUILD - >> Build Solution`
14. Na pasta: `C:\Users\<nomeDoSeuUsuario>\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\cvBlobsLib\x64\Release` Você encontrará a biblioteca cvBlobsLib.lib com 11,554 KB.

Você pode baixar o resultado aqui:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bctrg3o8jihnf2r/cvBlobsLib.lib